# What's the best way to test props you pass to child components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I'm testing a component using Vue test utils and Jest and I'm wondering what's the best way to test you are passing the correct values to a child components in it's props.

For example, test the values that the "items" attribute is given.

```
<template>
    <component-1 :items="myItems"/>
</template>
```

I know you can view the props with Vue test utils' props(), but is this the ideal way?

Comment: You can have a look at props validation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: @YashMaheshwari Prop validation is a good idea in general, but it doesn't catch the case of passing a valid, but still incorrect value. For example, a `profile-page` component might pass the valid mail address "john@mail.com" to its `contact-info` child component, which passes validation, although it should actually pass "john.doe@mail.com".

Answer (score 3):

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ParentComponent, {
  localVue,
  propsData: {
    ...
  }
})

const component1Props = wrapper.findComponent(Component1).props()

expect(component1Props.items).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining([
    {
      itemProperty: 'itemValue'
    }
  ])
)
```

Yes, that was the ideal way that worked for me.  Because I'm just testing the contents of the props passed to the child component, I did a `shallowMount` of the parent component, which stubs child components but still receives the props.  I called `findComponent` for the child component and then called `.props()` to inspect the props that have been passed in.